# Why UITextField with secureTextEntry clears its value when jumping to next field?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I have user registration screen with multiple UITextFields, one of them is password field with  secureTextEntry = YES. The problem is the password field gets cleared after entering password and jumping to next field (after touch on next field). Then same was happening when pressing keyboard return, but was able to workaround that:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
  NSString *text = textField.text; //copy password
  [textField resignFirstResponder]; // clears password field value
  textField.text = text; // put password back 
  return YES;
}
```

However, not able to workaround situation when focus moves to next field. Already banging my head for several hours with no solution. Probably missing something fundamental. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like a repeat of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305538/uitextfield-with-secure-entry-always-getting-cleared-before-editing

Comment: @grodier, nop, the text gets cleared not upon field edit, but upon focus lost.