# Auto transliteration in UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

The model problem: i want to auto convert all 1 to 0 under input in text field.

I try the following:

```
UITextField *textField = ...
textField.delegate = self.
textField.secureTextEntry = YES;
```

...................

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    BOOL ret = YES;

    if ([string isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        NSString *text = @"0";
        textField.text = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:text];
        ret = NO;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Now two cases:

1) we put focus in textField, type "1" then type "2". Result: text field contains only "2", "1" vanishes.

2) we put focus in textField, type anything but not "1" (for example "3"), then delete it, then type "1" and "2". Now we see that text field contains "12"!

What is the difference between these cases? Why does "1" vanishes in the 1st case after typing the next symbol?

P.S. Sorry, I forgot to write the definition of the textField. It is very important that it is of password type! If we try with ordinary textField, my code works perfectly.

Comment: No one can help you solve the problem with your code since you didn't post the `replaceRange:withText:` method.

Comment: You are right. Sorry, I've cleared this method, but use another one previously commented. They do the same.

Comment: 1) See my answer. 2) What is `self.text` and why do you expect the text field to be updated when you set the value of a string property (assuming `self.text` is a string property on this view controller)?

Comment: BTW - your code will only work if the user doesn't paste text into the text field and if the user doesn't ever move the caret.

Comment: inattentive copy paste (

Comment: This is the model example. In reality I intend to forbid any actions with password field. only simple keyboard typing. So it is enough for this problem. I only want to understand why password field behavior differs from simple text field

Comment: [Does this answer help?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14470008/3120884) or the one a couple later?  I think the issue is how iOS clears secure textfields on user edits, but heck if I understand the nuances.

Comment: @stevesliva I'll try it, thanks. Seems it should work.

Comment: @stevesliva I've solved the OP in another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my OP problem with the help of UITextInput protocol:

```
- (BOOL)changeRussianCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        string = @"0";
        [self replaceRange:self.selectedTextRange withText: string];
    }    
    else if (!string.length) {
        UITextPosition *start = [self positionFromPosition:self.beginningOfDocument offset:range.location];
        UITextPosition *end = [self positionFromPosition:start offset:range.length];
        UITextRange *textRange = [self textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];
        [self replaceRange:textRange withText: string];
    }
    else {
        [self replaceRange:self.selectedTextRange withText: string];
    }

    return NO;
}
```

One can easily extend this approach on any transliteration cases including copy/paste actions (with string.length > 1)