# UITextField secureEntry doesn't respect clearsOnBeginEditing property

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I'm building an app on iOS 8. I have a login screen where a user enters a username and password. When they have entered a valid username and password, they are allowed to move to the next screen (a button becomes enabled, allowing them to advance).

I have logic written that tells the button when to enable or disable itself, which is based off of the `UITextFieldDelegate` method:

`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`

This method tells me when my text fields are going to change their text - pretty simple. I have set my password text field's `secureTextEntry` property to be YES and its `clearsOnBeginEditing` property to NO.

When I leave the password textfield and then come back to it (by clicking inside of it) and type something, the text still gets wiped. Making things even more complicated, the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` method doesn't give me any indication that the text field is being cleared (based on the range or replacement string). And so I am not able to detect when to set my continue button back to disabled.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out a different design solution to the question, and am going to answer it myself. What I ended up doing was removing any logic related to changing the button state (enable vs disable) from `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`

I instead made my class an observer of `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`, and then performed my button state changes in the method I pass in when the notification fires. Here is what that subscribing / unsubscribing to that notification looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
}
```

I can then figure out what text field changed in my method like this:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[notification object];
    //perform logic here, change button state, etc.
}
```

I will admit that this might not be the best (or only) solution to the question, but it does serve the original problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `textFieldShouldClear` method as part of the `UITextFieldDelegate` to determine if you should disable the continue button.

Additionally, you can return `NO` in this method to keep the field from being allowed to clear if explicitly setting it's property is not working. However, you may want to do a check for tag or otherwise to prevent this from disabling clear on your username field.

**EDIT:**
See the answer listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7305603/2845237

> Note: *This won't work* if **secureTextEntry = YES**. It seems, by default, iOS clears the text of secure entry text fields before editing, no matter if **clearsOnBeginEditing** is YES or NO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This doesn't work for me, however. Even after implementing textFieldShouldClear, the method isn't called when the field clears.

Comment: From the apple docs (about textFieldShouldClear): "The text field calls this method in response to the user pressing the built-in clear button. (This button is not shown by default but can be enabled by changing the value in the clearButtonMode property of the text field.) " Since I am not using the clear button, it makes sense why this delegate method is not called.

Comment: I will say that reading the answer within that link clears the situation up a bit. Basically, from a UX perspective, secure entry text fields are ALWAYS going to clear on edit because it's almost impossible for the user to know what was in the field previously since it's turned into the black circles anyway. That being the case, I guess we need to try something different that prevent the text field from clearing. Hence why I think my solution below is decent.