# Overriding Native Control Method In Custom Renderer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an `ExtendedEntry` control that I use to extend functionality of my `Entry` controls for each platform.

In my custom renderer I have access to the `Control` property, which is the `UITextField`. This property allows me to easily change properties of the `UITextField` during runtime. Example:

```
public class ExtendedEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        Control.ClearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing;

        // ...
    }
}
```

On iOS I want to override the `UITextField` Control's `bool BecomeFirstResponder` method, which is virtual, however, I cannot override a class method like this at runtime.

How can I do this from the custom renderer?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you actually want to do within `BecomeFirstResponder`, but **without creating a custom subclass of `UITextField`**, you can create a custom `UITextFieldDelegate` and assign it to the `UITextField.Delegate` property.

If you are trying to prevent the field from becoming a first responder, you could use the `UITextFieldDelegate.ShouldBeginEditing` to return `false`, this method is called before `BecomeFirstResponder` is called) and `UITextFieldDelegate.EditingStarted` is called after `BecomeFirstResponder` is called:

```
public class TextFieldDelegate : UITextFieldDelegate
{
    public override bool ShouldBeginEditing(UITextField textField)
    {
        return base.ShouldBeginEditing(textField);
    }

    public override void EditingStarted(UITextField textField)
    {
        base.EditingStarted(textField);
    }
}
```

Refer to the following link to review the full order/flow of all the method calls of `UITextFieldDelegate`:

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate

Update:

Here is how I do the `SecureTextEntry` toggle / No clear field on edit:

1) Custom `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
public class SecureTextFieldDelegate : UITextFieldDelegate
{
    public override void EditingStarted(UITextField textField)
    {
        if (textField.SecureTextEntry != true)
        {
            var text = textField.Text;
            textField.DeleteBackward();
            textField.InsertText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

2) Setup your UITextField:

```
uiTextField.Delegate = new SecureTextFieldDelegate();
```

3) Handle Touch of toggle and/or physical keyboard field Tabbing:

```
uiSwitch.ValueChanged += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    uiTextField.SecureTextEntry = !uiTextField.SecureTextEntry;
    if (uiTextField.SecureTextEntry == true)
    {
        var text = uiTextField.Text;
        uiTextField.DeleteBackward();
        uiTextField.InsertText(text);
    }
};
```

The `UITextField.Text` now should never clear unless the user performs a *delete*

Comment: I am attempting to block the UITextField from overwriting the password field when focus is resumed and a user begins editing again (for a password visibility toggle button). This is the Obj-C solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37061759/1090359. I'll have a look at the delegate solution you posted and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @kspearrin Ah...the custom delegate is the way to go unless you are working with a subclassed `UITextField`..., checkout my update

Comment: I seem to be getting the following error trying to wire up the delegate in the custom renderer `OnElementChanged` `Control.Delegate = new SecureTextFieldDelegate();`. `System.InvalidOperationException: Event registration is overwriting existing delegate. Either just use events or your own delegate: ExtendedEntryRenderer+SecureTextFieldDelegate UIKit.UITextField+_UITextFieldDelegate`. Do I need to unregister some default delegate or something first?