# How to unclear UITextField secure text entry in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

When I use default **Security text Entry in UITextField** in Swift Language after type type text once UITextField.

[image: Image for When enter text first time]

Once loss focus from UITextField after try to edit Secure text then **UITextField is first reset and after it start put new text** in UITextField.

[image: Image for try to edit old text]

How to edit old Secure Text **without Storing data into Any Kind of String object**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44185845/4604231
I think that ↑ is a better way to solve it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to create a custom UITextField class and override [become​First​Responder()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder/1621113-becomefirstresponder) method do add your desired functionality:

> You can override this method in your custom responders to update your
>   object's state or perform some action such as highlighting the
>   selection. If you override this method, you must call super at some
>   point in your implementation.

The custom Class should be similar to:

```
class CustomSecureTextField: UITextField {
    override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        super.becomeFirstResponder()

        if !isSecureTextEntry { return true  }

        if let currentText = text { insertText(currentText) }

        return true
    }
}
```

The logic of the implementation of `becomeFirstResponder` as follows:

By default, the secured-entry text field clears the inserted text when it is become first responder text, so what's happening in `CustomSecureTextField` that if the text field is secured-entry, it will re-insert the current inserted text -after clearing it-, but *you have to make sure* that the text field input is secured (that's the purpose of adding `if !isSecureTextEntry { return true  }`) or the text will be duplicated (re-inserted) each time the text field becomes first responder.

**Output:**

Note that both of text fields are types of `CustomSecureTextField`:

[image]

Comment: Let me double check.

Comment: Sure! don't forget to let your text fields to be of type `CustomSecureTextField`

Comment: There is an issue with the above solution if you just tap the field simply it automatically inserts the text

Answer (score 2):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7305603/5515188) helped me to figure out this problem.

```
   textField.isSecureTextEntry = true
```

following property not gonna work if you make testField **isSecureTextEntrysecure** property makes **true** .

```
   textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = false
```

Comment: let me double check.

Comment: In here I also said it's impossible. swift not provide support.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the @Ahmd F solution when you simply tap on the field it will automatically add the text to the field I have resolved that in the below code thanks

```
override open func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    super.becomeFirstResponder()
    if !isSecureTextEntry { return true}
    if let currrentText = text {
        self.text = ""
        insertText(currrentText)
    }
    return true
}
```