# When I use secureTextEntry = {true} the input reset the value when try to type again

Tags: react-native

I'm using react native TextInput field for save a password value, so I added the `secureTextEntry` to hide the value. So I type the password and everything is good but if I go to other field let say username and I go back to the password and I want to add a new character to the password that I put it before the input gets clear and take the new character as the new password. So for example if I type "cat" and then I want to add another letter for example "o" it does not add like this: "cato" instead just set the value to "o"

I'm using the `onChangeText` to handle the state but I dont know what is happening there..

This is the input:

```
<TextInput onChangeText = {(pass) => this.setState({pass})} value = {this.state.pass} secureTextEntry = {true} />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS by default clears the text in a secure text field. 
See further discussion of this issue on the underlying UITextField at [UITextField with secure entry, always getting cleared before editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305538/uitextfield-with-secure-entry-always-getting-cleared-before-editing)