# TextInput with securTextEntry automatically clear when type something after losing the focus

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

I have an **TextInput** with **secureTextEntry** set as **true**. When I do the following steps this input unnecessarily clear all it's content:

1. Type something in the **TextInput**
2. Make any action to lose focus (as example **Keyboard.dismiss()**)
3. Tap **TextInput** again and type something
4. Previously entered text immediately clear and you start typing in an empty field

Is there a way to disable this strange behaviour and allow user continue typing the password from a point he stopped?

Comment: Certainly the way you handle the input, can you post your code ?

Comment: I finally found out that it's the default iOS behavior for any TextInput with secureTextEntry set as true. Probably there is a way to change it, but it requires some native iOS adjustments. On Android, everything works as expected.

Comment: Even I found the same thing, and thanks for the follow-up @Borutsky it saved my time.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305538/uitextfield-with-secure-entry-always-getting-cleared-before-editing