# numberpad return deleting all the text instead single char-ios

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

when Uitextfiled editing, press return button on numberpad deleting single char,
once keyboard dismiss view.endediting(true) and again focus, click delete(return) button
deleting all the text. i need only one char should delete. it is securedtextfield

Comment: Could you please add more info or code ?

Comment: I think you have enabled "Secure text entry" function in your UITextField, So It will automatically delete all the characters on the next becomeFirstResponder on it. And this is by default features for the password field. So i think we can't modify it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UITextField with secure entry, always getting cleared before editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305538/uitextfield-with-secure-entry-always-getting-cleared-before-editing)

Comment: @lazarevzubov - yes